# getline(cin, answer5); not working at the end of my program

Tags: c++, getline

In my program at the end I have used `getline(cin, answer5)` gets closed. I want to save the strings that I use as answers for the questions with using spaces between words to a notepad.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <fstream>

 using namespace std;
 int main()
 {
    string ques1 = "Client's Name :";
    string ques2 = "Client's Address :";
    string ques3 = "Mobile Number :";
    string ques4 = "ID No :";
    string ques5 = "Job Description :";

    string answer1;
    string answer2;
    int answer3;
    string answer4;
    string idc;
    string answer5;

    cout << ques1 << endl;    
    getline(cin, answer1);

    cout << ques2 << endl;   
    getline(cin, answer2);

    cout << ques3 << endl;
    cin >> answer3;

    if (cin.fail()) {
        cout << "Enter Numbers Only.." << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << ques4 << endl;
    }

    cin >> answer4;

    if (answer4.length() != 9) {
       cout << "Incorrect ID No.." << endl;
    }
    else
    {    
       idc.append(answer4);
       idc.append("v");
    }

    cout << ques5 << endl;
    getline(cin, answer5);

    ofstream saveFile("Save1.txt");

    saveFile << answer1 << endl
             << answer2 << endl
             << answer3 << endl
             << idc << endl
             << answer5;

    saveFile.close();

    system("pause>null");  
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put `cin.ignore();`
after this line :

```
cin>>answer4;
```

Comment: That works, can you tell me the reason why it should be there?